# Drop all rows id pandas df except ones mentioned in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have two dataframes, one containing lot of columns

```
df1:
id    age   topic     date   text
1     23    Student   1.1.   Lorem
2     19    Student   1.2.   Cupcake
20    19    Student   1.2.   Lorem Ipsum
190   21    Student   11.1.  Cupcake Ipsum
```

And one with two columns

```
df2: 
id   count
1    105
20   4843
31   361
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to drop all the rows from df1 that are not mentioned in df2 (their id is not there).

```
result_df:
id    age   topic     date   text
1     23    Student   1.1.   Lorem
20    19    Student   1.2.   Lorem Ipsum
```

I've tried this but it's not working:

```
result_df = df1.drop(df1[df1['id'] != df2['id']].index)
```

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```
result_df = df1.merge(df2['id'])
```

Given:

```
df1:
    id  age    topic
0    1   23  Student
1    2   19  Student
2   20   19  Student
3  190   21  Student

df2:
   id  count
0   1    105
1  20   4843
2  31    361
```

Doing:

```
result_df = df1.merge(df2['id'])
print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
   id  age    topic
0   1   23  Student
1  20   19  Student
```

Comment: This doesn't retain all columns from df1.

Comment: Yes it does. I'm just too lazy to figure out why copy/pasting OPs data gives an error, so I only used the first couple (easy to copy) columns.  It will work just fine with the complete dataset.

Comment: Got it. Looks good then.

Comment: @AkankshaAtrey Your idea of using just `df2['id']` was a good one though~

Comment: thanks! I just didn't test it enough before posting lol. Thanks for pulling it through.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')
result_df = df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)].reset_index()
```

Output:
result_df

```
   id   age topic   date    text
0   1   23  Student 1.1.    Lorem
1   20  19  Student 1.2.    Lorem Ipsum
```